# Fibonacci one-liner in Swift

Tags: swift, reduce, fibonacci

I'm attempting some code golf, I have this function:

```
    func fibonacci(n: Int) {

        var x1=0
        var x2=1
        var arr = [Int]()

        for _ in 1...n {
            arr.append(x1)
            let temp = x1+x2
            x1 = x2
            x2 = temp
        }
        print(arr)
    }
```

and I would like to try a one-liner namely this:

```
print((1...n).reduce(([Int](),[0,1]), { ($0.0 + [$0.1[0]],[$1.1[1],$1.1[1]+$1.1[0]])}))
```

But I get this lame-o compiler message:

> the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>   time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to actually construct an `Array`. You can use [the `sequence` function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence#) to generate the Fibonaccis one at a time:

```
sequence(first: (0, 1)) { a, b in (b, a + b) }
    .prefix(10)
    .forEach { a, _ in print(a) }
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

If you want to know more about the theoretical underpinnings of `sequence`, read about [anamorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism).

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is quite hard to read with all of the default parameters.  One of
the issues with attempting to do this is that the `Int` passed into `reduce` isn't actually needed inside the closure and you need to tell Swift to ignore it.  That is hard to do with default parameters, but if you add explicit parameters, you can use `_` for the one you want to ignore.

Here is a solution using two `reduce` statements:

```
print((1...n).reduce([0, 1]) { (f, _) in f + [f.suffix(2).reduce(0, +)] })
```

The second `reduce` is used to add the last two elements of the previous iteration obtained by `.suffix(2)` which is then appended to the array using `+`.

---

Instead of using the second `reduce`, you could also just add the last two values:

```
print((1...n).reduce([0, 1]) { (f, _) in f + [f.last! + f[f.count - 2]] })
```